# How does the series Lucifer end or how to find out?

Tags: ending, lucifer

I just found out that with the last episode of season 3, that will air tomorrow, Lucifer has found its end, Fox, canceled the series.

Is there a way to find out, how the series was supposed to end? There are still a few mysteries unsolved. 
I don't know much about canceled series, so is it common that the producers somehow tell the story in short text form or will it stay a mystery forever?

Comment: You have two different question here....do continuations in other media happen..yes, they do. Will it happen for *Lucifer*...too early to tell.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not sure that's what's being asked here, though. The question just wants to know if there is any information how the loose ends from TV-show were supposed to be concluded. Not sure we should interpret too much broadness or speculation into the question when it puts it quite bluntly at "Is there a way to find out, how the series was supposed to end?".

Comment: Fair enough...then *forever* is pretty vague. .

Comment: "Forever"...until someone provides an insightful answer to this question. ;-)

Comment: There is a decent campain to save Lucifer. NBC just saved Brooklyn Nine-Nine, so who knows?!

Answer (score 4):

From the current information, I believe there was nothing really written yet for the cancelled season 4, since initially whole series was supposed to finish at episode 18 in season 3

> On Twitter, Lucifer executive producer Joe Henderson indicated that the series will end with a closure in Episode 18. ‏”We designed this season to be an 18 episode arc because we originally were going to be 18 episodes. But then we got 4 more! Surprise!,” he wrote. “So we decided to create four episodes that let us play around a bit. Dig deeper into the character stories, play with format a bit, etc.” The four episodes “stand on their own, but also pick up plots we’ve introduced and bring in new stuff we’ll play with season 3  <sup>[source](http://deadline.com/2017/03/lucifer-supersized-season-3-4-season-2-episodes-migrate-2017-18-1202050153/)</sup>

Still, it seems that Henderson is disappointed in the cancellation and hopes that the show will come back:

> We created a season finale with a huge cliffhanger so that there was no way Fox could cancel us. Instead, we're going to frustrate the hell out of you fans. I'm so sorry for that. By the way, the Lucifer finale is the best hour of television I've been lucky to write. It wraps up everything from the season. But what it teases for season 4... well, maybe, just maybe, we can #SaveLucifer and show you.  <sup>source</sup>

In either way I wouldn't expect for the supposed whole series finale hints to surface any time soon - either they never existed or they do, but their leakage would damage any chances this show would have in resurfacing.

Answer (score 3):

Netflix has [revived Lucifer for its fourth season](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/lucifer-revived-at-netflix-fox-cancellation-1120632)

> The streaming giant has picked up the fantasy drama for a fourth season.
>   Lucifer is getting a second life.
>
> Netflix is reviving the canceled Fox drama for a fourth season. The DC Entertainment series, which hails from Warner Bros. Television, was axed in May. An episode count for the new season has yet to be determined.

The new season is expected to be half the number of episodes as a "typical" Lucifer series but at least the story will continue.

Comment: Netflix has also announced that the next season will be the last.  I do expect Netflix to bring the series to some sort of satisfying conclusion.

Comment: Season 5 was not the last, 6 was.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was asked under the conditions that Lucifer was being cancelled, but the current update is that Lucifer ran for 6 seasons and [has formally been wrapped up with its final season on 10th September 2021](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a37636425/lucifer-cancelled-season-7/).

It ends with

> **Lucifer** : finds his calling; helping redeemable souls in hell
>  **Chloe** : lives on Earth till her death and reunites with Lucifer in afterlife
>  **Dan** : in heaven with Charlotte Richards for eternity
>  **Amenadiel** : becomes the new God
>  **Maze** : marries Eve, and continues bounty hunting with her
>  **Trixie** : probably alive
>  **Rory** : returns to her original timeline
>  **Ella** : last shown being in a relationship with Carol (Dan's ex-colleague)
>  **Linda** : last shown raising Charlie on Earth